# Ajax is not redirecting to the given URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having a hard time finding the error of why my ajax is not performing or possibly not redirecting to the given URL on my ajax code.

I've tried troubleshooting by putting an alert message inside my php code just to make sure if it's redirecting, but it's not showing anything.

```
 $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     alert("hi");
     $.ajax({

         url: "unit_update.php",
         method: "POST",
         data: $('#insert_form').serialize(),

         beforeSend: function() {
             $('#insert').val("Updating");
         },
         success: function(data) {
             alert("SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED");
             $('#insert_form')[0].reset();
             $('#edit_data_Modal').modal('hide');
             $('#unit').php(data);

             setTimeout(function() {
                 location.reload();
             }, 100);
         },
         error: function(data) {
             $('#ErrorDiv').show();
             $("#ERRMessage").text("ERROR UPDATING");
         }

     });
 });
```

I'm getting the "hi" and the "SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED" message coming from my ajax code after pressing the UPDATE button but I'm not getting the Updated result on my database.

Comment: success: _A function to be called if the request succeeds._
So I assume there is something on the backend side.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event){  
    event.preventDefault();  
    alert("hi");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "unit_update.php",
        data: $('#insert_form').serialize(),
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#insert').val("Updating");
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert("SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED"); 
        $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
        $('#edit_data_Modal').modal('hide');  
        $('#unit').php(data);  
        setTimeout(function() {
            location.reload(); 
        }, 100);
    }).fail(function() { 
        $('#ErrorDiv').show();
        $("#ERRMessage").text("ERROR UPDATING"); 
    });  
});
```